How do I debug a JNI dll using Visual Studio C++ debugger?
I have written a JNI library. It works fine when running in java.exe - the output from printf in the C code is shown in the console. However, when I run java.exe from the Visual studio debugger - the debugger does not start, and an internal exception is thrown. I can still run java.exe from Visual Studio without debugging and it runs fine. I also tried to run a separate java.exe process and connect to it through the debugger. I receive lots of messages like this:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDA4CAB699 in java.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: JdsError<ipc::TimeoutExpiredError> at memory location 0x000000135E31F1C0

and nothing happens. I run the "Debug" configuration of my dll, of course. I loaded the dll using System.loadLibrary(...).
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (22.0.2+9) (build 22.0.2+9-70)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0.2+9-70, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)

I tried Oracle JDK 11, OpenJDK 11 - same result. The Java main() method is not even invoked when run under the debugger.
I use Visual Studio 2022

This question is similar to: How to debug a DLL that is being used from Java through JNI. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It was about debugger breaking when debugging. In my case it does not even connect to a java process.

[edit] the question to add version of Visual C++ IDE you are using to the question and the debug configuration.
